# UAC elevation prompt doesn't show password prompt. Why?

Tags: uac, hotfix

Windows 7; I've got UAC turned on, but I'm not logged in as an administrator. This means that when I click 'Run as Administrator', I'm prompted for the password for the Administrator account.

Until this morning.

I get the UAC prompt, which says "To continue, type an Administrator password and click Yes", but it doesn't display the administrator tile, and there's no password box to type into. The Yes button is disabled.

I've just installed Windows Server AppFabric (KB970622), which installed three other hotfixes ([KB980423](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=c8ad52b7-4b63-4547-9af7-839356e4f792&displaylang=en), [KB983484](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=830bb57e-f14a-46f0-97a9-ef48b9ab5000&displaylang=en) and [KB2300535](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2300535)). I guess that one of these broke it, but which one, since none of them appear to have anything to do with UAC?

Comment: Does it work correctly if you try when logged in on an admin-level account?

Comment: My only admin-level account is "Administrator", so I don't get any elevation prompt at all for that account. That does add another data point: I can still log in as Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just uninstalled Windows Server AppFabric (KB970622), but left the other three hotfixes, and the elevation prompt is working correctly. I'll try reinstalling it and see if it breaks again...

Update: yes, that broke it again. I'll uninstall it and go without.

Comment: You should report this bug to Microsoft here...http://connect.microsoft.com/dublin

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the link. I reported it on the Azure MSDN forums. I'll file it on Connect as well.