# UAC: Windows does not display Yes button or password field

Tags: windows, permissions, user-accounts, uac

#### Related issues, not a duplicate of:

- ["Yes" is disabled in Windows 10 elevation dialog](https://superuser.com/q/1020273/320611)
- [Automate UAC to not prompt for admin user/pass when app needs "run as administrator"](https://superuser.com/q/1202025/320611)
- [UAC elevation prompt doesn't show password prompt. Why?](https://superuser.com/q/206581/320611)
- [How do I enable pressing "y" for the UAC prompt? Only arrow keys work](https://superuser.com/q/456787/320611)

#### Problem

When trying to elevate a program to run as administrator, the **Yes** button is not displayed, and I cannot enter the administrator password to continue.

[image: User account control - Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?]

The only message that is appeared:

**To continue, enter an admin user name and password.**
There is only a **No** button.

Why isn't a **Yes** button displayed?

#### Additional information

The machine has two user accounts:

1. The main user account (I would like this to have limited permissions)
2. The built-in administrator account, having elevated permissions

[image: Windows user permission groups]

I would like to use the limited main user account with limited permissions, and type out the Administrator account's password when a program requires elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

This is caused when the current user does not have Administrator permissions, and Windows is not finding another account where the following requirements are met:

1. The account should be in the **Administrators** group
2. The account should be **active**
3. The account should *NOT* be **hidden**/**special**

If any of the above requirements aren't met, Windows will not display the password field.

#### Option 1 – using the current account

Using safemode or other means (e.g. replacing `sethc.exe` to a copy of `cmd.exe`) you can add the current user to the **Administrators** group.  This will allow you to type out your password (and/or press "Yes") using your current account credentials, when a UAC prompt appears.

#### Option 2 – using another elevated account

When using an account that has sufficient permissions (e.g. using the above method first), you can assign correct permissions to another account for the purpose of using it when elevated permissions are required.

1. Open **`lusrmgr.msc`** → **Users**
2. Choose an existing account (e.g. `Administrator`, or create a new one (Action → New User)
3. Open **Properties** for that user
4. Make sure the "Account is disabled" checkbox is **unchecked**
5. (Optional) Also uncheck "User cannot change password",
   and check "Password never expires"
6. Make sure the user is a member of the following groups:

   - `Administrators`
   - `Users`
7. Open `REGEDIT.EXE` and navigate to the following path:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`
   Make sure a DWORD key with the same name of the user (e.g. **Administrator**) doesn't exist, or if it does, the value isn't set to **`0`**. (e.g. the value should be set to **`1`**).

#### Option 3 – using the run as dialog

This option only works if you are confident that a privileged account with the correct username and password combination **does** exist on the machine, but Windows is refusing to display the password field in the UAC dialog.

This usually can happen if the privileged user does have correct permissions, but is not visible (e.g. the *step 7* of the above option is not met).

In order to run a process (such as `cmd.exe`) as another user, follow these steps:

1. Follow a shortcut by right click → Open file location
2. Hold **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** and **Right-click** on the executable
3. Hold **<kbd>Shift</kbd>** and click **Run as different user**
4. Enter credentials for the other user, hit Ok

This will allow you to run the executable as the other, privileged account (which also allow you to follow the option 2 within the elevated window).

Comment: On 2021-07-16: Option 3 is the workaround that I was searching for. First option seems like causing security problems, may be not, but too mutch of a hack. Second option is obvious and does not entirely work for Windows 10 Home edition although the final step does. The root of the problem is that the UAC window is incomplete by missing a text input to type the username.

Comment: I had to press Shift when I clicked "Run as different user" in Windows 11. Otherwise it just gave me the same blank option as shown in the question screenshot.